# How to get jmDNS ServiceInfo description string

Tags: java, android, networking, jmdns

How to get description string of jmDNS ServiceInfo whitch we specify in 4 parameters of this overload:

```
ServiceInfo mServiceInfo = ServiceInfo.create(TYPE, SERVICE_NAME, PORT, DESCRIPTION);
```

What method can I get value from *DESCRIPTION* variable of this instance.

*Thanks in advance, regards...)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following website has the documentation for the `ServiceInfo` class. http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/apidocs/javax/jmdns/ServiceInfo.html

The method you're looking for is `ServiceInfo.getNiceTextString()`, which "Returns a description of the service info suitable for printing." This method returns the entire DESCRIPTION variable in a printable string. You can also use the `getPropertyNames()` method with the `getPropertyBytes(String name)` or `getPropertyString(String name)` methods to get specific TXT entries and their values. For instance, if your DESCRIPTION variable is `"color=blue"` then you can call `ServiceInfo.getPropertyString("color")` and it will return `"blue"`.